# GPS Location Background Tracking and Alerts

Tags: ios, gps, location, cllocation

I'm sure this has been discussed many times but I'm having trouble finding a clear answer.

While the app is in the background, and an array of gps coordinates, how can I monitor the current location of the user and make comparisons to the list, alerting the user when they are within a certain distance to them. Locations in the list could number in the thousands and could be in locations worldwide.

Much like Reminders will alert you when you are near a location you choose but in this case the user would not be choosing the location.

Ive read this post [Background location tracking: iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614557/background-location-tracking-ios) which discusses Regional Alerts.  Just hoping something new has come out since then.

I've looked at stuff like Alohar api.  And CLLocation.

Can anyone venture a guess as to how Reminders works?

I don't need any specific code.  Just some general pointers and ideas.

I'm thinking, perhaps I do something along the lines of ...

```
- Get user location
- Compare to list of GPS locations
- Narrow list to a reasonable radius from user
- Increase frequency of location checking if narrow.list > n
- Increase frequency of location checking if nearest_location < t
- Decrease frequency of location checking if narrow.list < n && nearest_location > t
- Decrease frequency of location checking if nearest_location > t
- Stop checking if user hasn't moved in x min.
- Start checking again when user starts moving x distance from stationary point.
```

I don't know.  Just thoughts.  Any help is appreciated.

-m

Comment: Sorry, mainly I'm looking to conserve battery and do it correctly.  I know how to query the location and all that.  I'm looking for pointers on doing it right for my purposes.